# How to reconfigure a control box unit for an SCN5 actuator

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering

An image of the actuator is below. I have a setup that was given to me where there is two configurations, namely 50mm travel and back, and 75mm travel and back to home position. There are two switches PC1 and PC2 which control the two programs via the CSRT switch.

[image]

Now I would like to extend the system to 4 program, example

- home, 100mm travel, home
- home, 75mm travel, home
- home, 50mm travel, home
- home, 25mm travel, home

To achieve this I plan to add 2 more switches, PC4, and PC8. After I add the switches my control box will look something like the following.

[image]

Below is an example wiring diagram.

[image]

Below is an example of the programming interface.

[image]

Below is an image of the electrical wiring interface.

[image]

**Question:** How do I wire the PC1, PC2, PC4 and PC8 so I can independently control 4 settings? Only 1 switched can be ON for a program. The other 3 switches have to be closed.

I am also open to hearing alternate solutions.

Here is the link for the vendor who sells the SCN5 actuator in question.

https://www.miraiintertech.com/home/scn5.php

Comment: Check this out [BFF Motion Driver (v2.6+) - SCN5 Actuator Start Guide](http://bffsimulation.com/Images9/BFF-Motion-Driver-SCN5-Actuator-Start-Guide-1_1.pdf), [SCN5 Wiring Tutorial](https://www.xsimulator.net/community/threads/scn5-wiring-tutorial.5566/) & [Mechatronics Cylinder SCN Series Operation Manual](https://www.miraiintertech.com/home/downloads/SCN-SCL-Manual2011.pdf)

Comment: "Question: How do I wire the PC1, PC2, PC4 and PC8 so I can independently control 4 settings? Only 1 switched can be ON for a program. The other 3 switches have to be closed." well for  a start get your head round electrics not pneumatics. Only 1 switched can be ON= CLOSED for a program. The other 3 switches have to be OPEN." would make sense but I personal would not do it like that for a small cylinder.

Comment: @Brad, `I personally would not do it like that for a small cylinder`. Can you please tell us how you would do it.

Comment: @Mahendra Gunawardena well with small cylinders you often get the situation where two feedbacks are showing because of the physical limitations on the positioning of the reed switches (or electronic equivalent). So you have to allow for this in your software whilst still keeping the program safe. "Counting and latching" positions is one option. (example Position 1, 1 light on - Position 2, 2 lights on etc) Also there should be 5 switches in the program (maybe there are, the question is not detailed) But you need to use ZFIN as the 1st & 5th position switch.

Answer (score 0):

For starters connect PCx signal wires as below to the following switches

Switch 1 wire to PC1
Switch 2 wire to PC4
Switch 3 wire to PC1, PC2 and PC4
Switch 4 wire to PC2 and PC8

Position No 1,4,7 and A

[image]

---

**Switch 1**
Position 1 => 0mm, program next
Position 2 => 100mm, program next
Position 3 => 0mm

**Switch 2**
Position 4 => 0mm, program next
Position 5 => 75mm, program next
Position 6 => 0mm

**Switch 3**
Position 7 => 0mm, program next
Position 8 => 50mm, program next
Position 9 => 0mm

**Switch 4**
Position 10 => 0mm, program next
Position 11 => 25mm, program next
Position 12 => 0mm

---

**Reference:**

- [Fast and quiet linear actuator for lifting less than a kilo](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/7318/fast-and-quitet-linear-actuator-for-lifting-less-than-a-kilo?rq=1)
- [Dyadic SCN6 actuator recovering from Alarm condition Using 24V signal](https://youtu.be/CVk1x9GJu4A)