# Three switches executing the same program for SCN5 Actuator

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, actuator

As indicated in [How to reconfigure a control box unit for an SCN5 actuator](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/40702/how-to-reconfigure-a-control-box-unit-for-an-scn5-actuator/42318#42318)  question I want have 4 actuation programs as described below

- home, 100mm travel, home
- home, 75mm travel, home
- home, 50mm travel, home
- home, 25mm travel, home

Controlled by 4 independent switches

I want only one switch to be closed at one time, so connected signals PC1, PC4, and PC8 as follows:

1. Switch 1 wire to PC1
2. Switch 2 wire to PC4
3. Switch 3 wire to PC8
4. Switch 4 wire to PC4 and PC8

I used 2 Position  toggle switches part number 7343k713 from McMaster-carr

The programs are as follows

**Switch 1**
Position 1 => 0mm, program next
Position 2 => 100mm, program next
Position 3 => 0mm

**Switch 2**
Position 4 => 0mm, program next
Position 5 => 75mm, program next
Position 6 => 0mm

**Switch 3**
Position 8 => 0mm, program next
Position 9 => 50mm, program next
Position 10 => 0mm

**Switch 4**
Position 12 => 0mm, program next
Position 13 => 25mm, program next
Position 14 => 0mm

[image]

---

**Question:**

Switch 2, 3 and 4 all execute the program 4 (Switch 4). PC2, PC4, and PC8 are connected together. How do I separate PC4 and PC8 connecting the SW4?

Comment: This link might be helpful [Learn to wire and program a low-cost servo actuator in 7 minutes](https://youtu.be/IdnukwZMbcE)